# firebase - Как получить токен пользователя?

Tags: android, firebase

У меня имеется приложение android. Через панель firebase я могу всем отсылать различные оповещения.

Также, там есть пункт, где указано, что можно отправить конкретному пользователю, но нужно указать  токен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: где взять этот токен ? он где-то в панели firebase хранится или его нужно как-то получить из приложения?

Comment: Из приложения..

Comment: как и где его хранить ?

Comment: Когда авторизуетесь из приложения в Firebase, то получаете токен.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы про токен пользователя то можно отслеживать получение нового токена в Вашей реализации FirebaseMessagingService в методе

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
   //Реализуем логику сохранения токена
}
```

UPD: Не заметил дату вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что имеется ввиду id регистрации, но это не точно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен токен, который генерируется на клиенте посредством вызова

`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`;

Более детально вы можете ознакомиться с этим в гайде по [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).

Comment: Этот вариант уже устарел, см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125169/what-to-use-now-that-firebaseinstanceid-getinstance-gettoken-is-deprecated.